# How to access object property that has a date format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to access some data from NASA's API, which is in a nested object. Their data is sorted by date, so each key is formatted like so: 2018-09-07

```
const asteroidList = this.props.asteroids.near_earth_objects //works fine, can access data up to this point
console.log(asteroidList)
```

```
const asteroidList = this.props.asteroids.near_earth_objects[2018-09-07] // "Legacy octo literals are not allowed in strict mode" ????
console.log(asteroidList) //errors out
```

I cannot access anything past this point, because I keep getting an error from my text editor. I'm assuming there must be some kind of conversion method or something to read dates that I don't know about, but I can't find anything for object key-value pairs.

Comment: Shouldn't `2018-09-07` be in quotes `""` like `["2018-09-07"]`

Comment: Could you post the json you received back?

Comment: @Farah10 _"Cannot read property `'2018-09-07'` of `undefined`"_. It means that chain is fine upto `this.props.asteroids` but `near_earth_objects` is not property of `this.props.asteroids`. Can you please post the data

Comment: There could be a bunch of reasons it's undefined.  Maybe you're trying to use it before it's got any data in it, for example.

Comment: @MaheerAli I'm dumb. I tried that and was getting back "Cannot read property "2018-09-07" of undefined", so thought that wasn't the solution. Turns out I had to put it in quotes and do a ternary to make sure I wasn't displaying the data before running the API call. Of course I figure it out right as I post this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Farah10 post your `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

I check what `NASA APIs` response is, and the key is not a `date-value` but the `"date"` string.

So if you have a list of objects and you want to access only the one with a specific date you have to iterate over those objects and search for that particular object:

```js
const list = [
    {
        "date": "1995-06-16",
        "explanation": "Today's Picture:    Explanation:  If the Earth could somehow be transformed to the ultra-high density of a neutron star , it might appear as it does in the above computer generated figure. Due to the very strong gravitational field, the neutron star distorts light from the background sky greatly. If you look closely, two images of the constellation Orion are visible. The gravity of this particular neutron star is so great that no part of the neutron star is blocked from view - light is pulled around by gravity even from the back of the neutron star.   We keep an  archive file.  Astronomy Picture of the Day is brought to you by  Robert Nemiroff and  Jerry Bonnell . Original material on this page is copyrighted to Robert Nemiroff and Jerry Bonnell.",
        "hdurl": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/e_lens.gif",
        "media_type": "image",
        "service_version": "v1",
        "title": "Neutron Star Earth",
        "url": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/e_lens.gif"
    },
    {
        "date": "1999-07-11",
        "explanation": "Today's Picture:    Explanation:  If the Earth could somehow be transformed to the ultra-high density of a neutron star , it might appear as it does in the above computer generated figure. Due to the very strong gravitational field, the neutron star distorts light from the background sky greatly. If you look closely, two images of the constellation Orion are visible. The gravity of this particular neutron star is so great that no part of the neutron star is blocked from view - light is pulled around by gravity even from the back of the neutron star.   We keep an  archive file.  Astronomy Picture of the Day is brought to you by  Robert Nemiroff and  Jerry Bonnell . Original material on this page is copyrighted to Robert Nemiroff and Jerry Bonnell.",
        "hdurl": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/e_lens.gif",
        "media_type": "image",
        "service_version": "v1",
        "title": "Neutron Star Earth",
        "url": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/e_lens.gif"
    },
    {
        "date": "2010-01-22",
        "explanation": "Today's Picture:    Explanation:  If the Earth could somehow be transformed to the ultra-high density of a neutron star , it might appear as it does in the above computer generated figure. Due to the very strong gravitational field, the neutron star distorts light from the background sky greatly. If you look closely, two images of the constellation Orion are visible. The gravity of this particular neutron star is so great that no part of the neutron star is blocked from view - light is pulled around by gravity even from the back of the neutron star.   We keep an  archive file.  Astronomy Picture of the Day is brought to you by  Robert Nemiroff and  Jerry Bonnell . Original material on this page is copyrighted to Robert Nemiroff and Jerry Bonnell.",
        "hdurl": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/e_lens.gif",
        "media_type": "image",
        "service_version": "v1",
        "title": "Neutron Star Earth",
        "url": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/e_lens.gif"
    }
]

list.forEach(element => {
    if (element.date === '1999-07-11') {
        console.log(element);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass *2018-09-07* inside quotes `"2018-09-07"`
Also add check for undefined cases to avoid error.

```
const asteroidList = this.props.asteroids && this.props.asteroids.near_earth_objects && this.props.asteroids.near_earth_objects['2018-09-07']
console.log(asteroidList)
```